# Craft Commerce 3 calling commerce/payments/pay from Axios returns errors

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I have headless Craft CMS + Craft Commerce 3 + Mollie for Craft Commerce as backend and decoupled Nuxt.js frontend

I'm trying to use POST request to `"?action=commerce/payments/pay&note=from+ajax"` to submit payment.

I have two different scenarios in which I'm receiving an error from backend:

1. Passing the following body:

   ```
    "email": "mail@example.com",
    "gatewayId": 4,
    "paymentMethod": "ideal",
    "issuer": "ideal_ABNANL2A",
    "redirect": "/checkout/success",
    "cancelUrl": "/checkout/payment",
    "orderNumber": "050dfb9df12054210f7171270b77dd83",
    "cartUpdatedNotice": "Pay the order"
   ```

returns me the 400 error `"Request contained an invalid body param"`

2. Passing the body without "cancelUrl" and "redirect" gives me the 500 error:`Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\UrlHelper::siteUrl() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/kooij/domains/kooij.com/craft/vendor/craftcms/commerce-omnipay/src/base/Gateway.php on line 506`

Can you tell me what is wrong/missing there ? Thank you